# How to make TCP Client accepts hosts

Tags: c#, tcp

My TCP Client should:

1. accepts host, port and a text string.
2. connects to a host/port and sends the string (+ two lines feeds \r\n\r\n )when you click a button.
3. then reads the results and puts the results back in a text box.

The problem that I get a result of the port and string , BUT I DON'T GET ANYTHING ABOUT THE HOST.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net.Sockets;


   namespace TCP_Client
   {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string port = port1.Text;
        int myParsedInt = Int32.Parse(port);
        System.Net.IPAddress[] adresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host1.Text);

        Socket connectSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        connectSocket.Connect(adresslist[0], myParsedInt);
        System.IO.StreamReader connectionRead = new System.IO.StreamReader(new NetworkStream(connectSocket));

        connectSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendText.Text + "\r\n"));
        while (connectionRead.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            this.textOutput.AppendText(connectionRead.ReadLine() + "\r\n");
        }

        connectSocket.Close();
    }

    private void textOutput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void host1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void port1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void sendText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where should you see something about the host? Maybe you should show us the server code.

Comment: it should goes to sendText.Text

Comment: So, you're trying to receive the text that you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) class?

Unless you need low-level socket IO, you may find this class to be easier to deal with (certainly it's easier for the use case you have here).

On TcpClient the constructor (or Connect) can accept a hostname, and there are methods which provide access to the NetworkStreams (inbound and outbound)

The MSDN example in that link includes more-or-less exactly what you're trying to do.

**EDIT:**
Would you please be more explicit about exactly what's wrong?  Is the DNS resolution failing, or do you get a valid IP?

Is your server seeing the traffic?  Have you tried calling Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send) after sending your text?

Comment: i'm using low-level socket IO. i'm not allowed to use TcpClient class for this assignment

Comment: it takes more than 2 min to show the result. and the result is usually something like this :         the client.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at new.utm.edu Port 80</address>
</body></html>